# Rails / Jquery Autocomplete auto complete plugin for city, country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Im looking for a good Jquery plugin that can handle
finding the country a city belongs to ( on type with autocomplete )

for example:

```
Typing "New Yor"
```

Should autocomplete to

```
New York, United States
```

And be able to save the city and country as

```
:city
:country
```

What would be a good way of achieving such functionality? I mean more in terms of storing all the country's and city's in the user database. I know https://github.com/jim/carmen but that one is being rewritten and I would love to figure this out myself, with a little help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Might as well write your own logic for this since I don't think a plugin is going to present itself:

I'm assuming the city and country have ids.  If not, the logic would actually be simpler.
Use jQueryUI's autocomplete to trigger the autocomplete for your element.  Add a controller method, that will give your city and country label (likely a method on a city object) along with your ids back as json.  In the autocomplete "select" callback, set hidden fields in your form for city and country ids. This last part is optional because I don't know how you plan to persist this data from the form.

The following examples assume A LOT about your app, but should be enough to get you started:

example of script for the view:

```
    $("#yourField").autocomplete({
      source: "/path_to_your_action",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        $(this).find("#country_id").val(ui.item.country_id);
        $(this).find("#city_id").val(ui.item.city_id);
        event.preventDefault;
      }
    })
```

controller:

```
def your_action
  term = params[:term]
  cities = City.where("cities.name like ?", "%#{term}%")
  .limit(25)
  .all
  render :json=>cities.collect{|c| {:label=>c.your_label_method, :city_id=>c.id, :country_id=>c.country_id}}
end
```

city.rb

```
def your_label_method
  "#{self.name}, #{self.country.name)}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the better solution to me is using the google map api to know a good return. You can by example use the plugin htp://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker.

Comment: Thanks I look into this, leave the question open for some more response This could work with some modifications only problem is you then have no control over the returned values. USA instead of United States. I would prefer a local solution with own country database. thx though for pointing out the gem